# How can we evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty nx^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

If the right side of integral is finite, we can shift limit into to the integral, but how ? $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty nx^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)dx$

Comment: Sure that these simply exist?

Comment: the integral is equivalent to $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin(y)}{y^4}dy$ which clearly diverges, and you can not change the limit with the integration

Comment: **Hint:** $\sin t\approx t$ when $t\to0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the integral exists we have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}nx^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)\,dx=\frac{1}{n^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\,dx,$$
however $x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$ since for every $x\geq\frac{2}{\pi}$ we have $\sin\frac{1}{x}\geq\frac{2}{\pi x}$, so 
$ x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\geq \frac{2x}{\pi}$.

Comment: what if  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 nx^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)dx$ ? if so, $\sin(1/nx)<1$ and $x^2\leq 1$ becouse we are in [0,1]. so, the function in the right side of integral is always $<n$, then we may swap lim into the integral.

Comment: @kaya: in such case we have: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\int_{1/n}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y^2}\,dy = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the integrals won't converge for any $ n $ because the integral over $ x> n/\pi $ is $\infty $ while the rest is finite.